# Crash after navigating to question from notification menu

Tags: bug, android-app

As the title says, the app crashes for me whenever navigating to a question from the notification menu. Strangely, it only happens after scrolling the page a bit.

App version: 1.0.35
Device: Motorola RAZR HD, 4.1.2

Here's all I get from LogCat:

```
A/libc(6366): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 6366 (exchange.marvin)
```

[This may be relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14495305/1107110)

Comment: It might be better to add versions app and device. Just to be sure that's not a device's problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce on nexus 7 with 1.0.35. Could you post a log of the crash?

Comment: @Howlin Updated with log.